# Vectorized calculation of a column's value based on a previous value of the same column?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, difference

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns `A`,`B` as below.

I want a vectorized solution for creating a new column C where `C[i] = C[i-1] - A[i] + B[i]`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

>>> df 
     A  B
 0  10  0
 1   2  1
 2   3  2
 3   4  3
 4   5  4
 5   6  5
```

Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877196/conditional-replace-based-off-prior-value-in-same-column-of-pandas-dataframe-pyt) using for-loops:

```
df['C'] = df['A']

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df['C'][i] = df['C'][i-1] - df['A'][i] + df['B'][i] 

>>> df
    A  B   C
0  10  0  10
1   2  1   9
2   3  2   8
3   4  3   7
4   5  4   6
5   6  5   5
```

... which does the job.

But since loops are slow in comparison to vectorized calculations, **I want a vectorized solution for this in pandas**:

I tried to use the `shift()` method like this:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].shift(1).fillna(df['A']) - df['A'] + df['B']
```

but it didn't help since the shifted C column isn't updated with the calculation. It keeps its original values:

```
>>> df['C'].shift(1).fillna(df['A'])
0    10
1    10
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
```

and that produces a wrong result.

Comment: Good question, but your example data is not great since all the differences `df['B'] - df['A']` are -1 except the first row, so you wouldn't notice off-by-one bugs in solutions, indexing errors etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be vectorized since:

- `delta[i] = C[i] - C[i-1] = -A[i] +B[i]`. You can get `delta` from `A` and `B` first, then...
- calculate cumulative sum of `delta` (plus `C[0]`) to get full `C`

Code as follows:

```
delta = df['B'] - df['A']
delta[0] = 0
df['C'] = df.loc[0, 'A'] + delta.cumsum() 
​
print df
    A  B   C
0  10  0  10
1   2  1   9
2   3  2   8
3   4  3   7
4   5  4   6
5   6  5   5
```

Comment: Thanks @Happy001 it works perfectly. Its also a useful lesson for the future: If you stuck, do some algebra and rethink your problem.

Comment: This is really neat. If you can come up with a vectorized way of doing `delta[0] = 0`, you could make it a one-liner and eliminate `delta` entirely, which will be more performant on large dataframes.